# Diferença entre Date, sql.Date e Calendar

Tags: java, data

Qual a é diferença entre as classes `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date` e `java.util.Calendar` e em quais situções é recomendado o uso de uma ou outra?

Comment: O recomendado é usar o [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) :)

Comment: O recomendado é usar JSR-310. Vem com Java 8, e pode ser baixado para o Java 7.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

O melhor é entender isso do ponto de vista histórico.

A primeira versão de Java tinha uma classe para data e hora: `java.util.Date`. Essa classe contém uma informação: um instante no tempo. Faz sentido falar em "antes" ou "depois" com essa classe, ou usá-la como um "timestamp" para saber quando alguma coisa aconteceu.

A classe `java.sql.Date` também está lá desde o início, e observe que *ela estende `java.util.Date`*. Ela serve, basicamente, para passar que o JDBC (acesso a banco de dados relacional) possa converter entre `java.util.Date` e o `DATE` do SQL. Não se preocupe com essa classe -- se você precisar dela, você vai saber.

Antes de ir ao `Calendar`, vamos ver alguns problemas com `Date`. Primeiro, você pode obter dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo, mas *não tem informação sobre time zone*. Ou seja, se você tem um `Date`, não dá para saber se é relativo ao horário de Brasília ou de Nova Iorque (que dirá horário de verão). Ou, mais precisamente, ela sempre se refere ao horário GMT.

Além disso, essa classe não permite fazer contas do tipo "daqui a dois dias" ou "daqui a duas horas" -- você tem que implementar a lógica para isso você mesmo. Em certos aspectos é até fácil: some a quantidade de segundos necessária. Mas se você precisar lidar com coisas como horário de verão, é simplesmente impossível.

Por fim, essa classe só permite uma representação de `String`: a americana. Se você precisar ler ou escrever em qualquer outro formato, está por conta própria.

A classe `java.util.Calendar` e algumas outras (particularmente `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`) foram introduzidas no Java 1.1, doadas pela IBM a partir do código de uma de suas afiliadas (a Taligent), para solucionar esses problemas. Ela introduz time zones, horário de verão, e localização (ou seja, converter de/para strings com o formato adequado para a língua e região).

Basicamente, `Calendar` seria usado para qualquer coisa que não seja saber em que instante um evento aconteceu.

Então, qual usar? **NÃO USE NENHUMA DESSAS CLASSES**. Elas são cheias de defeitos -- eu precisaria de uma resposta inteira só para discorrer a respeito -- e existem alternativas muito superiores.

Você deve usar, preferencialmente, as novas classes no pacote `java.time.*`, introduzido com Java 8. Se você não tem Java 8 mas tem Java 7, use o backport dessas classes, o [threetenbp](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Se você não tem nem isso, use o [JODA Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), que foi criado justamente por conta dos problemas com as classes originais do Java, e que foi o ponto de partida para as novas classes do Java 8.

Comment: Excelente explicação. Obrigado.

Comment: Uma das respostas que mais uso como referencia nas minhas aqui no SOPT :)

Answer (score 19):

**`java.util.Date` - [Date (Java SE7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)**

É uma classe que representa data.

Possui algumas versões sobrecarregadas de construtor, seus construtores não obsoletos são:

```
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis()); //o construtor vazio já atualiza a variável com a data
                                      //e hora atuais
}
public Date(long date) {
    fastTime = date; //sua declaração é: private transient long fastTime;
}
```

Logo, o código a seguir

```
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
System.out.println(d);
```

Emite o seguinte resultado:

```
Thu Apr 10 10:36:15 BRT 2014
```

**`java.sql.Date` - [Date (Java SE7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)**

É uma subclasse do `java.util.Date`.

Possui dois construtores, um deles está obsoleto, portanto recomenda-se utilizar o seguinte:

```
public Date(long date) {
    // If the millisecond date value contains time info, mask it out.
    super(date); //chama o construtor do java.util.Date
}
```

Sua principal vantagem é que uma variável de referência dessa classe pode ser usada diretamente em um Sql Statement.

**`java.util.Calendar` - [Calendar (Java SE7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)**

É uma classe abstrata que possui métodos úteis de conversão e comparação de data, por exemplo:

```
public static Calendar DateToCalendar(java.util.Date date){ 
  java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(); //instancia um BuddhistCalendar
                                         //ou um GregorianCalendar dependendo das
                                         //configuracoes do seu computador

  cal.setTime(date); //seta a data do java.util.Date para sua variável de referencia
                     //considere que a data passada foi o do primeiro exemplo,
                     //ou seja: Thu Apr 10 10:36:15 BRT 2014
  System.out.println(cal.after(new java.util.Date())); //retorna false, pois hoje não
                                                       //é depois de hoje
  cal.add(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1); //subtrai um da hora do cal
  System.out.println(cal.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)); //retorna 9, que é a hora
                                                               //do cal (que foi subtraida 
                                                               //logo acima)
}
```

Alguns exemplos de métodos úteis são:

```
add(int field, int amount) //para somar um período de tempo à data da váriavel
after(Object when)         //para comparar se data atual é depois da data do when
before(Object when)        //para comparar se data atual é antes da data do when
```

dentre outros.

**Joda-Time**

Muitos dos comportamentos das classes `java.util.Date` e `java.util.Calendar` são considerados estranhos para a maioria dos programadores Java, por isso a biblioteca [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) é a preferida quando a programação envolve data e hora.

Joda-Time possui a classe [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), que tem a capacidade de substituir por completo ambas as classes. Exemplo:

```
org.joda.time.DateTime joda1 = new org.joda.time.DateTime();//inicializa com data/hora atuais
System.out.println(joda1); //imprime 2014-04-10T11:35:09.000-03:00

//cria um novo objeto com 5 horas a menos que o joda1
org.joda.time.DateTime joda2 = new org.joda.time.DateTime(joda1.minusHours(5)); 
System.out.println(joda1.isAfter(joda2)); //retorna true
```

O exemplo acima mostra apenas alguns dos inúmeros métodos que a classe possui, ela possui mais métodos do que as classes que a classe substitui e todos eles costumam ser muito intuitivos.

Comment: Uma desvantagem muito discutida do Joda-Time é que informações sobre *time zones* e horário de verão mudam com frequência e se você não atualizar manualmente a biblioteca ela pode gerar valores incorretos. Lógico que o mesmo acontece se a pessoa usar `Calendar` em uma JRE antiga. Bem, isso foi algo que eu li há algum tempo. Pessoalmente nunca tive problemas em usar o `Calendar`.

Comment: @utluiz Sobre o Calendar, não consigo me lembrar assim de cabeça o que ele deixa a desejar, mas eu sei que já tive contratempos, já o joda sempre achei simples e versátil. Sobre a discussão, nunca tinha ouvido sobre, talvez pq eu nunca precisei de muita precisão no calculo das horas, nos meus casos errar por uma ou duas horas nunca foi um problema, geralmente o que se usa é a data, mas é sempre bom saber essas peculiaridades.

Comment: O maior problema da classe `Calendar`, do meu ponto de vista, é sua mutabilidade. Não podemos mudar o conteúdo de Strings e dos wrappers primitivos, mas o mesmo não é verdadeiro para o `Calendar`. Isso pode levar a problemas sérios se algum método inadvertidamente modificar a instância que passamos.

Answer (score 9):

`java.util.Date` é uma classe simples e só existe mesmo por razões de compatibilidade com versões anteriores. De verdade não é muito útil, pois só guarda datas, sem as operações de manipulação.

`java.util.Calendar` veio depois e cumpre esta função, de definir datas específicas ou fazer aritmética de datas, `java.util.Calendar` também pode lidar com a localização. As funções de manipulação de data da `java.util.Date` já foram descontinuadas.

Ambas são mutáveis​​.

`java.sql.Date` extende `java.util.Date`. Possui mais algumas propriedades para trabalhar com bancos de dados.