# Subtrair datas em JAVA em pegar a diferença de dias

Tags: java

Eu preciso calcular o dia de gestação que uma mulher está, tendo a informação da data em que a mulher ficou grávida e a data de hoje.

Eu tenho a seguinte instrução:

```
Date dtToday = new Date(); //pega a data de hoje
Data dtEngravidou = Mommy.getDtPregnantDate(); //retorna a data em que ficou grávida
```

Em teoria, eu precisaria subtrair a data de hoje com a data da gravidez e eu teria o numero de dias que já se passaram, sendo assim eu teria a diferença, ou seja, com quantos dias de gravidez a mamãe está.

Comment: Seu Date é um java.util.Date? Já considerou a possibilidade de usar um JodaTime?

Comment: É sim java.util.Date. Nunca ouvi falar nessa biblioteca, sou novo no mundo java. Pode postar uma resposta de como seria isso usando essa biblioteca JodaTime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode fazer essa conta utilizando as classes [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) e [Duration](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) da biblioteca JodaTime.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Duration;

public class CalculaDiff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime dtToday = new DateTime(); //pega data e hora atual
        DateTime dtOther = new DateTime(DateTime.parse("2014-06-15T08:00:55Z")); //exemplo

        Duration dur = new Duration(dtOther, dtToday); //pega a duração da diferença dos dois

        System.out.println(dur.getStandardDays());
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> 16

Você pode fazer o download dela aqui: [Joda - Time](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/)

[Nessa resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12568/3117) tem uma boa explicação do por que de não usar as bibliotecas padrões.

Comment: Perfeito, no meu caso precisei para Android, existe uma lib dela mais rápida por não usar o JAR que é esta aqui [link](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android). No entanto para fins de solução o JodaTime resolveu perfeitamente. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Agora, com a as APIs padrões do Java 8, é possível fazer:

```
LocalDate dtToday = LocalDate().now();
LocalDate dtEngravidou = Mommy.getDtPregnantDate();
long diasDeGravidez = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dtEngravidou, dtToday);
System.out.println("Mamãe está grávida há " + diasDeGravidez + " dias");
```