# Diferença de datas com calendar em um TextField

Tags: java, swing, datetime, java-8, comparação

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para hotel e gostaria de automatizar alguns recursos no sistema.

Gostaria que, quando selecionasse duas datas sendo a `dataEntrada` e `dataSaida`
utilizando o Calendar, fazer com que ao escolher estas datas, aparecer a diferença dos dias em um `TextField` nomeado `QdtDiaria` automaticamente. Seria possível?

Comment: Está usando java8? Ou precisa ser no java7?

Comment: java 8 estou usando

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma usando as classes do pacote [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):

```
 public long subtrairData(Date dataEntrada, Date dataSaida) {

    LocalDateTime LocalDataEntrada = dataEntrada.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    LocalDateTime LocalDataSaida = dataSaida.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();

    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDataEntrada, LocalDataSaida);
}
```

Funcionando no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/00GPLs).

> Obs.: leia [nesta
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12568/28595)(créditos ao @Math
>   pelo link) uma boa explicação sobre o porquê usar as classes do pacote java.time para
>   comparar datas, e não as classes nativas mais antigas, como `Date` e
>   `Calendar`.

---

## UPDATE

E para preencher um `JTextField` com essa diferença dentro de uma ação de botão(conforme dito nos comentários), é só fazer a chamada do método citado dentro do `setText()` do seu componente, desta forma:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        myJTextField.setText(String.valueOf(subtrairData(dataEntrada,dataSaida)));
    }
});
```

Como o retorno do método, apesar de ser em dias, é tipo `long`, é preciso fazer a conversão para `String`, utilizando `String.valueOf()`.

> Obs.: Deve-se validar os valores dos campos de data antes de passá-los como parâmetros do método acima, para que não cheguem vazios ou datas inválidas, evitando assim o lançamento de exceções.

**Referencias:**

[Subtrair datas em JAVA em pegar a diferença de dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23076/28595)

[Calculate days between two dates in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27005861/5524514)

[Java 8: Calculate difference between two LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25747499/5524514)

[Convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21242110/5524514)

Comment: Boa tarde! Realmente não fui clara na minha questão! Gostaria de saber se após a ação de um botão que utilizo fosse possível o preenchimento 
de um TextField automaticamente.

Comment: @Lizy como eu disse na resposta, você não deixou claro que tipo de textfield estava se referindo e nem qual o tipo da sua aplicação.

Comment: JTextField Java Swing - Campo de texto

Comment: @Lizy respondendo de forma curta: sim, é possivel. basta passar os Dates dos 2 campos para esse método dentro do actionperformed. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Obg @DiegoF!!! Vou testar!!!

Comment: @Lizy deu certo?

Comment: sim obg @Diego F