# Retornar quantidade de dias para o fim do ano

Tags: java, data, java-8

Como eu poderia fazer para retornar a quantidade de dias para o final do ano, contando com o dia de hoje.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TestLocalDate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Data de hoje
        LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();

        //ultimo dia do ano 31/12/2016
        LocalDate faltaFimDoAno = hoje.with(Month.DECEMBER).withDayOfMonth(31);


        System.out.println("Hoje: " + hoje.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))); //saida: Hoje: 28/08/2016

        System.out.println("Ultimo dia do ano: " + faltaFimDoAno.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))); //Saída: Ultimo dia do ano: 31/12/2016

        System.out.println("Quantidade dias para o fim do ano: " + Period.between(hoje, faltaFimDoAno).getDays()); //Quantidade dias para o fim do ano: 3

    }

}
```

O método `Period.between(hoje, faltaFimDoAno).getDays());` Está retornando a quantidade de dias e não a quantidade total contando dias, mês e ano.

Comment: Dividir por 30 não seria a solução?

Comment: Pode ser. Mas queria fazer com a api java.time

Comment: Você quer o total de dias até o fim do ano apenas ne? Sem informar meses.

Comment: Isso mesmo, mas o método .getDays retorna a quantidade de dias do dia 28 até 31 que são 3

Comment: ok aceitei aqui =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa é usar a função [`toDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#toDays--) do [`Duration.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-):

```
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear;
//...

LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate faltaFimDoAno = hoje.with(lastDayOfYear());

long dias = Duration.between(hoje.atStartOfDay(), faltaFimDoAno.atStartOfDay()).toDays();

System.out.println("Quantidade de dias para o fim do ano: " + dias);
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/cwVylR)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`ChronoUnit`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) para efetuar essa comparação:

```
//Data de hoje
LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
//ultimo dia do ano 31/12/2016
LocalDate faltaFimDoAno = hoje.with(Month.DECEMBER).withDayOfMonth(31);


System.out.println("Hoje: " + hoje.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))); 

System.out.println("Ultimo dia do ano: " + faltaFimDoAno.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));

System.out.println("Quantidade dias para o fim do ano: " + ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(hoje, faltaFimDoAno));
```

Saída:

> Hoje: 28/08/2016
>   Ultimo dia do ano: 31/12/2016
>   Quantidade dias para o fim do ano: 125

Veja no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/2ilwjy).

Comment: Chegou primeiro por uma meia dúzia de segundos hehehe :)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly já tinha idéia da resposta, só achei que ele queria uma descrição por completo como  "Faltam x meses e x dias para o fim do ano". Ai eu não saberia fazer, por hora.

Comment: Rolava com `Period.between`, de lá você chama `getDays`, `getMonths`, etc. De qualquer forma esse pacote `temporal` é bem escondido. A única diferença entre a minha resposta e a sua era que eu estava usando [`LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjuster.lastDayOfYear())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastDayOfYear--), outra jóia escondida.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você queira uma solução usando [JAVA 1.8+](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) , pode-se usar o [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html), senão pode fazer também desta forma abaixo usando [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) e [GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) compatíveis com versões inferiores:

```
Calendar data1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar data2 = new GregorianCalendar(data1.get(Calendar.YEAR), 11, 31);

int diasRestantes = data2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - data1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
System.out.println("Restam "diasRestantes + " dias para acabar o ano!");
```

Boa Sorte!

Comment: Conforme [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12498/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-date-sql-date-e-calendar/12568#12568) não é uma boa idéia usar mais essas classes para compararação de tempo.

Comment: @diegofm vou dar uma pesquisada mais afundo sobre o assunto. Nunca aconteceu nenhum problema até hoje comigo, mas acredito que vale a pena ler um pouco mais a respeito! Abraços.