# Modificar Datas de cada objeto - MONTH, YEAR

Tags: java, data, calendar

Tenho um aplicativo onde crio um lançamento de por exemplo 400 reais e antes de salvar defino a data de criação e em quantas vezes tenho que fazer. Depois salvo.

E neste momento que salvo eu adiciono o lançamento a um `Array` de lançamento. Se fiz em duas vezes, tenho que pegar a data que definir e modificar as datas, por exemplo:

30/10 primeira parcela e depois 
30/11 a segunda.

Como posso modificar esta datas do lançamento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solução 1 (Recomendado):** No **Java 8** você pode utilizar a nova API **`JSR-310`** inspirada na `Joda-Time`. Esta biblioteca pode também ser baixada para o **Java 7** [aqui](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.threeten%7Cthreetenbp%7C1.3.2%7Cjar):

```
LocalDateTime.from(data.toInstant()).plusDays(1);
```

---

**Solução 2:** Você pode utilizar também a bibliteca [`Joda-Time`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), que facilita bastante o uso de elementos de data e hora no Java:

```
DateTime dataJoda = new DateTime(data);
dataJoda = dataJoda.plusMonths(1);
```

---

**Solução 3:** Use a classe `Calendar` da seguinte forma, onde a variável `data` é um `Date` com a data definida:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(data); 
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
data = c.getTime();
```

Esta solução não é recomendada seguindo a extensa explicação dada neste tópico [Diferença entre Date, sql.Date e Calendar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12498/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-date-sql-date-e-calendar/12568#12568), que se resume a:

> NÃO USE NENHUMA DESSAS CLASSES. Elas são cheias de defeitos -- eu precisaria de uma resposta inteira só para discorrer a respeito -- e existe alternativas muito superiores.

---

**Método de cálculo**

Utilizando a **`JSR-310`** a implementação ficaria similar ao exemplificado a seguir:

```
private List<LocalDateTime> calcularDatas(LocalDateTime dataBase, Integer quantidade) {
  List<LocalDateTime> resultado = new ArrayList<>();
  Integer indice;

  for (indice = 0; indice < quantidade; indice++) {
    resultado.add(dataBase.plusMonths(indice));
  }

  return resultado;
}
```

Referência: [How to add one day to a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005523/how-to-add-one-day-to-a-date), [Diferença entre Date, sql.Date e Calendar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12498/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-date-sql-date-e-calendar/12568#12568)

Comment: Usar calendar pra isso é uma péssima opção. Sem duvida ou se usa joda time para versoes menores que 8 do java, ou usa o pacote java.time para versoes mais recentes.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12568/28595

Comment: Blz, vou adicionar na resposta

Comment: Pronto, acho que agora ficou mais claro e com as melhores opções

Comment: Utilizei a classe Calendar, por ser mais simples de lidar no momento. Estou começando em java e não tenho a prática diária ainda, mas vou estudar o que me recomendaram, JSR-310.