# Como exibir a data e hora "em tempo de execução"?

Tags: java, swing, datetime

Gostaria de saber como exibir a data e hora atual do computador, e a hora deve ser atualizada em tempo de execução. Eu pensei em passar um objeto para um label, mais não deu. Não vou guardar essa data, só quero que seja exibida,  queria colocar em um label para que eu possa posicionar em qualquer lugar depois.

```
package teste;

import static java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TelaSistema extends JFrame {

    public JLabel label = new JLabel();
    public JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    public TelaSistema() {
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("Teste");

        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

        label = new JLabel("Data aqui");

        painel.add(label);
        add(painel);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        TelaSistema tela = new TelaSistema();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obs.: Sempre inicie a tela dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info),
>   pois swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a GUI precisa iniciar dentro
>   desta unica Thread. [Nesta
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2095/28595) explica melhor o
>   motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra
>   resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas
>   maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

---

Utilizando as classes do pacote `java.time`, você pode fazer conforme abaixo:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TelaSistema extends JFrame {

    public JLabel label = new JLabel();
    public JPanel painel = new JPanel();

    public TelaSistema() {
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setTitle("Teste");

        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime timePoint = LocalDateTime.now();

        label = new JLabel(timePoint.format(fmt));

        painel.add(label);
        add(painel);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new TelaSistema()); 

    }
}
```

A classe `DateTimeFormatter` é responsável por formatar a data e a classe `LocalDateTime` é uma das novas classes da API para se trabalhar com tempo.

---

E para fazer com que a data seja atualizada em tempo real, você pode criar um [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) que force o label a atualizar a cada determinado tempo, neste caso, 1 segundo. Para facilitar trabalhar com o label, utilizei uma classe a parte que estende de `JLabel`:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ClockLabel extends JLabel {

    public ClockLabel() {
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, e -> setText(getDateTime()));
        t.setInitialDelay(0);
        t.start();
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        return LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

Adicione esta classe no seu projeto e depois basta instanciá-la:

```
label = new ClockLabel();
```

Veja um exemplo em funcionamento:

[image: GIF animado da tela]

---

Recomendo a leitura [**desta pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/28595) para aprender a trabalhar com essas novas classes, elas são otimizadas para se trabalhar com tempo, e também a leitura [desta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/12568/28595) explicando alguns motivos de se evitar trabalhar com as classes antigas para manipular datas.

Comment: esse LocalDateTime captura a hora, mais ele não atualiza ela em tempo de execução ?

Comment: @Java exibe a hora e data atual no momento da execução daquela linha de código. Você quer que exiba o relogio em tempo real?

Comment: isso mesmo! É possível ?

Comment: @Java resposta atualizada

Comment: Muito obrigado !

Comment: Acho que usar `Timer t = new Timer(1000, ae -> setText(getDateTime()));` melhor, pois dispensa a `ClockLabel` de ter que implementar publicamente uma interface que é apenas um detalhe de implementação que deveria ser privado, resultando então em um encapsulamento melhor.

Comment: O seu `main` deveria ter `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new TelaSistema());` - leia [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2017/132) para entender o motivo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa verdade, passou despercebido o EventQueue, copiei o código do OP mas acabei não notando isso na hora. Quanto a classe ClockLabel, eu optei por ela por dar a possibilidade de reaproveitamento, se tiver mais de uma tela, por exemplo, poder apenas estanciar para exibir as horas seria mais prático.

Comment: Fiz a alteração e adicionei o link que você mencionou sobre a EDT.

Comment: Você não entendeu o meu comentário sobre a `ClockLabel`. Acho a classe ótima. O meu questionamento é acerca do `implements ActionListener`.